# Как записывать данные полученные в процессе диалога с Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

В программировании я новичок на перед прошу прощения за кривоватый код и прошу вас объяснять поподробней. Пишу телеграмм бота через библиотеку pyTlegramBotAPI, суть следующая: идет диалог с ботом, бот задает вопросы собеседник отвечает и ответы собеседника должны записываться куда-то что бы потом эти ответы можно было получить. Я это сделал вся инфа записывается в блокнот но этот вариант плох тем что если пишут одновременно 2 человека то все ломается.Так вот как сделать эту запись по другому или исправить то что есть?

```
import telebot
import os
token = "Token"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def privetctive(message):
    sent = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, как я могу к вам 
обращаться?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sent, Hello)


def Hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте, {name}. К кому роду 
деятельности вы относитесь  ?'. format(name=message.text))
    doc = open('file.txt', 'w')
    doc.write("Имя заказчика - {imia}\n".format(imia=message.text))


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    user_markup.row('Test1', 'Test2')
    user_markup.row('Test3', 'Test4')
    user_markup.row('Test5')
    uslugi = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Какие услуги вас 
интересуют?", reply_markup=user_markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(uslugi, telephon)
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Род занятости - {zanatie}\n".format(zanatie=message.text))


def telephon(message):
    nomer = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оставьте ваш контактный номер 
что бы наш менеджер смог связаться с вами.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(nomer, poka)
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Услуга - {uslugi}\n".format(uslugi=message.text))


def poka(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Спасибо за обращение. Мы сяжемся с 
вами в ближайшее время.')
    doc = open('file.txt', 'a')
    doc.write("Телефон - {telephon}\n".format(telephon=message.text))
    doc.close()
    file_to_send = open('file.txt', 'rb')
    bot.send_document(000000000, file_to_send)
    file_to_send.close()
    os.remove('file.txt')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.polling()
```

Comment: Может быть, писать в разные файлы? Наверняка же есть у каждого пользователя какой-то уникальный идентификатор, его можно использовать для получения неповторяющихся для разных собесдников имён файлов, при этом то, что скажет один человек, будет храниться в единственном файле

Comment: Или каждый чат писать в отдельный файл, если вдруг может так получиться, что надо различать разные диалоги с одним и тем же человеком. Я вижу, что есть некие `message.from_user.id` и `message.chat.id`, так можно имя файла делать наподобие `'texting_' + str(message.chat.id) + '.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать словарь или defaultdict из модуля collections, где в качестве ключа - id пользователя, а значения - словарь данных о пользователе

```
users = {}
```

Или

```
from collections import defaultdict
users = defaultdict(dict)
```

> defaultdict полезен, когда данных о пользователе ещё нет, но Вы не хотите проверять, есть ли этот пользователь у Вас в базе или нет. [Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) по defaultdict

Если хотите сохранить эти данные, то используйте [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) и signal при отключении бота

```
import signal, pickle, sys
users = ...

def handler(**args):
    with open('settings.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(users, f)
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
```

Здесь мы обрабатываем сигнал остановки, поступающие нашей программе. И перед выходом из программы, сохраняем *users*

#### UPDATE:

Для того, чтобы достать значение *users* из файла *settings.pkl*(если он **существует**) Вам нужно написать следующее:

```
import os, pickle

if os.path.exists('settings.pkl'):
    with open('settings.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        users = pickle.load(f)
else:
    users = ...  # значение по умолчанию
```

Comment: `users = dict()` медленнее чем `users = {}` и в случае с `defaultdict` не обязательно писать `lambda: {}` можно сделать так: `defaultdict(dict)`

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая (в какой-то степени) ситуация - надо было сохранять настройки, которые запрашивал юзер для парсинга, в общем не суть.
Я развернул MS SQL сервер и данные закидывал в базу, использовал библиотеку **pypyodbc**.